# GWT: Load different css in host page

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I have gwt application based on GWTP. App supports two versions (tablet & desktop) and uses different widget libraries (sencha gxt and sencha touch). These libraries require different css files in host page. Moreother css are in conflict each to other. How I can load different css files in my host page?

I already read about [gwt mobilewebapp sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/#samples/mobilewebapp), but they use single html-page and different implementations of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this on the server side, by using a JSP file as the css source.
Then, in the JSP file, decide which set of properties to send based on the requesting user agent or other.

Another option is to write the host page as a JSP file, and it can include the proper CSS file based on the request.
This is a pretty easy way to go, but you must enable the JSP processor in your web.xml.  It also requires your deployed system to have a java compiler on it, which is not the case if you only install the JRE on the webserver.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Useragent and decide which CSS File to deliver.

I recommend to use [ClientBundles](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#CssResource). This deliver only the css styles need, and speed up your page.

In your Entrypoint you just decide which css file you want to deliver:

```
if(useragent == "desktop") {
   YourStyle.getTheme().getMGWTClientBundle().getDesktopCss().ensureInjected();
} else {
   YourStyle.getTheme().getMGWTClientBundle().getAppCss().ensureInjected();
}
```

or you can make a [switch inside your css files](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#Conditional_CSS). But you have to use ClientBundles anyway.

There you can have something like this:

```
@external gwt-button;
@if user.agent safari {
    .gwt-Button {
        ...
    }
}
```

@external gwt-button is to avoid obfuscation errors. you can also use @external *;

Comment: This approach results in bugs with css-parsing and obfuscation. So it is not appropriate.

Comment: you have to use CssResource correctly, this is just a snippet. If you want to know more about CssResource read the documentation, but this is a recomandation how to use it. In your case, you don't use external gwt-button probably. Or just external * to have no obfuscation. I have changed my code to make it clear.

Comment: We talk about css of two libraries. These styles are quite complicated (with browser's tricks). Look on reset.css in GXT3 for example. There is no ability to add @external for each css-selector.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two classes which load the css  file :

You can do some thing related to type in gwt.xml file

```
<replace-with
    class="com.test.classMobile">
    <when-type-is
        class="com.Test.classBrowser" />
    <when-property-is name="tablet.user.agent" value="ipad" />
</replace-with>
```

Just try this..I am not sure 100%